# What should be used for ios app devepopement swift or react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am android developer, now I want to start `iOS` app development, so I need to know which is better swift or react native to start for `iOS` development and which has better future.

Answer (score 1):

Guess react native is better. See the opinion from an ios developer

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/an-ios-developer-on-react-native-1f24786c29f0#.yyib1dviq